# How does "Format editor" for JFormatedTextField in NetBeans work?

Tags: netbeans

I need to edit format for JFormatedTextField in a Java program. NetBeans are "helping" me with something called Format editor. But, I have no clue how the pattern works.
[image: format editor]

For `#,##0.###` , it returns `1,234.567`, as pictured above. However, I want to change the thousands delimiter to space and decimal separator to comma.

I would guess `# ##0,###` is the right format, but no, that returns "Malformed pattern # ##0,###".

How can I change the thousand separator to space and decimal to comma? Is that even possible, using Format editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the reference for the [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class.

The [`DecimalFormatSymbols.getGroupingSeparator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getGroupingSeparator()) method looks like it is probably relevant to what you're doing. You will have to choose an appropriate `Locale` to get the formatting characters you want.

You may need to do something like:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
```

with an appropriate parameter to `getInstance()` for your country and language.

Comment: it's not EXACTLY what I wanted, and I still don't understand the mysteries of this Format editor, but you set me on the right track, so thanks!